# I am attempting to create a firebase login page on a web app, however when I attempt to login, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a login page for an app on a test project.  I have created a profile for me to test this with.  I have followed some tutorials and looked at the firebase database, but nothing seems to work.  I tried setting up an alert to go off when the login finishes, but that doesn't seem to happen either.  Currently, the function has just the code from the site, the alert and the necessary gets for the function

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/analytics";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

var firebaseConfig = {
   //appropriate values are here, but i'd rather not dox my test project
};


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

function login(event){
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredentials) => {
    var user = userCredentials.user;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
  alert("pancake2s")
  
}
```

```html
    <body onload="redirect()">
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='NS' style='font-size: 3vw; margin-bottom: 11vh; font-stretch: ultra-expanded;'>Your Political Action Kit</div>
            <div class='inner NS' style='margin-bottom: 23.5vh'>
                <form onsubmit="login(event)">
                    <div style="height: 7vh; font-stretch: ultra-expanded; color: rgba(225,226,240,1); margin-left: 9vw; margin-top: -1.5vh;">Please Login</div>
                    <label for="email"  style="margin-top:1.5vh;">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"  style="margin-top:1.5vh;"><br>
                    <div style="height: 2.5vh"></div>
                    <label for="password" style="margin-left:0.75vw;">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                    <div style="height: 2.5vh"></div>
                    <button class="YPAK_Button" type="submit">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/__/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

This is what I am currently working with.  While the JS file is pretty much all there, my HTML page is not fully there.  However, these are the relevant parts of my code.  I am pretty sure I set up the project correctly, so there has to be some issue in this code.  I don't have a ton of experience with Firebase and I've exhausted all the text/video resources I can find, so I am trying here to see if someone can help.

Comment: Move that `alert()` in then() block and try.

Comment: You do not cancel the form submission

Comment: @Dharmaraj I originally had an alert in the then block, but nothing happened, so I removed it  to see if it was causing the problem.

Comment: @epascarello would something like event.PreventDefault() be something I should try?  I was attempting to use it before, but it seemed to break the algorithm.  If not, should I remove the form submit entirely since I am calling by id and just have the button run the function onclick?  Or is there another command I can put in to cancel the form submission?

Comment: @JoshSolders See the duplicate: changing the button type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` should do the trick.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I changed the button type, but now it won't run the function period.  I attempted adding onclick="submit" similar to the article above and onclick="login(event)", but it won't even run an alert when I make it the first statement in the function.  I don't think its running the function period now that I removed the submit keyword.   I know that my main.js is loading.  However, it does not seem to want to run it and I am unsure as to why.

Comment: Doing `<form>...<button class="YPAK_Button" type="button" onclick="login()>Login</button></form>` together with adapting the function declaration as `function login(){...}` should do the trick.